# VSTS and VS 2017 pro - team explorer cant see other branches besides master

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Visual Studio professional 2017
I have a repo setup and 2 other branches besides master, yet when Im viewing "branches" within team explorer, I only see the master branch under "remotes" and not the other two.  What can I check?

Comment: Did you sync your branches with the remote?

Comment: I think I missed that.  Once I did, the other branches show up.  thanks!